# set value of rating from database using rateyo plugin

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, rating

I am using this rateyo plugin in my application. There is a page where user can give rating to an entity. But before giving rating I am making a check, if that user already assigned a rating to that particular entity and if the user does, then I fetch rating value from database and set it as the plugin says. But if it is a new user, he can submit his new rating.

here is the code what I am implementing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#rateYo").rateYo().on('rateyo.set',function(e, data){
            $.ajax({
                type : "post",
                url : "PostRatingValue.php",
                data : {
                    "rating" : data.rating,
                    "peopleid" : celeb_id,
                    "userid" : user_id
                },
                dataType : "json",
                success : function(response){
                    if(response.toString() == "true"){

                        $.growl.notice({ title: "Growl", message: "Rating<b> "+ data.rating +" </b>assigned successfully" });
                    }
                    else{
                        $.growl.error({ message: "<b>Unable to assign rating.</b>" });
                    }
                },
                error : function(response){
                    $.growl.error({ message: "<b>Something went terribly wrong! :'(.</b>" });
                }
            });
        });
```

below is the code to set the rating value if it exist.

```
<?php
            if(isset($fetchRatingIdAndValue['ratingpoints'])){
        ?>  
                $("#rateYo").rateYo("option", "rating", <?php echo $fetchRatingIdAndValue['ratingpoints'];?>);
        <?php       
            }
        ?>
});
```

Problem is that, when old rating is set, an ajax call is made which inserts same data again in table. I want my ajax call to work only when I need to set new rating or edit previous rating. I am not able to find the way out for this. Please help.

Comment: See how it works here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45523742/how-can-i-use-rate-yo-jquery-star-rating-plugin-with-data-attribute/57359306#57359306

Answer (score 1):

When you set the rating after Initialization of rateyo, `rateyo.set` event will be fired on the element.

Please do not do that, instead If already old rating exists, pass it during initialization itself like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rateYo").rateYo({

      rating: <?php echo $fetchRatingIdAndValue['ratingpoints'];?>
    }).on('rateyo.set',function(e, data){

        $.ajax({
            type : "post",
            url : "PostRatingValue.php",
            data : {
                "rating" : data.rating,
                "peopleid" : celeb_id,
                "userid" : user_id
            },
            dataType : "json",
            success : function(response){
                if(response.toString() == "true"){

                    $.growl.notice({ title: "Growl", message: "Rating<b> "+ data.rating +" </b>assigned successfully" });
                }
                else{
                    $.growl.error({ message: "<b>Unable to assign rating.</b>" });
                }
            },
            error : function(response){
                $.growl.error({ message: "<b>Something went terribly wrong! :'(.</b>" });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

`$fetchRatingIdAndValue['ratingpoints']` should contain `0` if user has not given any rating previously.